# Network Manager is Not Sending Notification When Connecting to VPN Server in MX Linux

Tags: networking, vpn, notifications

I am using MX Linux 21 XFCE pretty much unchanged from stock. I manually create VPN connections in Network Manager using Openvpn.  Its been pretty much trouble free for the most part.

One day I was suddenly not receiving network connection notifications when connecting to either ethernet or wifi and also when connecting to a VPN server (which I do manually). I did not choose "don't show this again!"

I asked on the MX forum and they told me how to turn nm-applet back on on using the MX Settings GUI. Normally I would have used dconf, but that is not an option in MX.

After turning notifications back on, I marked the request solved because I thought it was fixed. And it was partially. I got notified when connecting to the eth0 or wan0 but not when connecting to a VPN server like I used to.

Given the circumstances I assume that a plug-in configuration file (perhaps for OpenVPN?) did not get the message to turn notifications back on. Does anybody know the following:

1. How to fix this?   OR
2. How to find out what plugins are in Network Manager and where they keep their configuration files.

Goggling for two hours found lots of interesting network problems but nothing about notifications except how to turn them on and off the usual way and nothing about notifications for VPN connections.

P.S. I do confirm that the VPN connections are working after connection using {$ nmcli con show --active}. I have not had any problem with VPN connections except when using the VPN provider's software.  Works perfectly using Openvpn except for the sudden loss of notifications for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes saying something (or writing something) out loud sparks an idea.  As I was writing my question I realized that changing my search criteria to something entirely different might lead to better results.

Yup, it sure did. So here is the solution:

I decided the answer had to be in dconf.  What I found out was how to use the command line to find out what schemas and keys are used for individual applications in dconf.  There are more than half a dozen for nm-applet, three of which have to do with notifications. VPN connections have a separate setting.

Apparently using the GUI configuration editor and simply turning notifications on for nm-applet in MX does not convert true to false for all three applicable notification settings.

After some sleuthing I found a website about "gsettings." "Gsettings" is what you use on the command line to alter the settings in dconf. I didn't know about "gsettings" because I always used the GUI editor for dconf in the past with other distributions. For some reason the GUI seems to be seriously limited in XFCE.  I used `gsettings list-keys` to get the name of the keys and then `gsettings list-schemas` to get the names of the available settings.

This command solved the problem :

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nm-applet disable-vpn-notifications false
```

Now this happy camper can stop fiddling with the computer and get back to actually using my computer to do work.

I doubt that this will be of much use to anyone since I could not find a single other person on the internet with a similar problem!